# Issue with createElement() don't change data when I call new data

Tags: javascript, html, json

When I press on div "User" bring me posts for this user but when I change to another user imposed deletes autmicaly for old user posts and bring to me posts for a new user, unfortunately, it shows posts for new user bottom of the posts for old user.

Deleted old posts and bring to me new posts on the same div.

This function for create elements posts:

```
 function getPost(userID){
         fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId='+ userID)
         .then((response) =>{
            if (response.ok) {
               return response.json() 
            }
         
         })
         .then((posts) => {
            for(let post of posts){
               const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
               const orginalPost = document.querySelector("#demo")
               console.log(orginalPost);
               // orginalPost.style.display="none";
            //     //orginalPost.innerHTML='';  
                let newPost = document.createElement('div')
                newPost.innerHTML = orginalPost.innerHTML;
                newPost.classList.remove("orginal")
                newPost.className = 'info';
            // //    //console.log('new post ',newPost);
                let postHead = document.querySelector(".postHead")
                let postP = document.querySelector(".postP")
                     postHead.innerHTML = post.title;
                     postP.innerHTML = post.body;
            // //    //const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
                     parentPosts.appendChild(newPost)
                    remove(parentPosts)
            }
                         return
         });
      }
```

This function is supposed to remove old posts

```
 function remove(element) {
         let elementLength = element.children.length;
         console.log("element.children.length >> "+elementLength)
         if (element > 0) {
            element.firstChild.remove()
            //element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
            console.log("element.children.length from loop >> "+ elementLength)
}
  }
```

This all code

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
body{
   background: linear-gradient(120DEG,#c0a397,#ebe6b4);
}
         .conterner{
         width: 100%;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: row;
         }
         .users{
            margin: 2px;
            background: white;
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
         }
         .infos{
            margin: 2px;
            background: white;
            width: 70%;
         }
         .user{
            border-radius: 65px;
            background-color: rgba(187, 200, 200, 0.315);
            margin: 0 auto;
            cursor: pointer;
         }

         .user:hover,
         :active{
            border: rgb(224, 152, 132) 2px solid;
         }
         h3{
            padding: 1px;
            margin-left: 25px;
         }
         .info{
            border-radius: 23px;
            background-color: rgba(187, 200, 200, 0.331);
            margin: 8px;
            padding: 2px ;
            padding-left: 20px;
         }
         .line{
            width: 97%;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            /* position: relative; */
            }
            .dispaly{
               display: none;
            }
            .orginal{
               display: none;
            }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <main>
         <div class="conterner">

            <div class="users " >
               <div style="margin: 0 a;" id="parUser">
                  <div class="user" id="user" >
                     <h3 id="name"> Ahmed </h3>
                     <h3 id="email"> Ahmed.ali@gmail.com </h3>
                  </div>
               </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="info orginal" id="demo">
               <h5 class="postHead" > post post postpost</h5>
               <div class="line"></div>
               <p class="postP"> post post postpost</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="infos">
               <div class="info">
                  <h5 class="postHead" > post post postpost</h5>
                  <div class="line"></div>
                  <p class="postP"> post post postpost</p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        
      </main>
      <script>
         

         function getUsers(userID){

       fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
         .then((response) =>{
            if (response.ok) {
               return response.json() 
            }
         
         })
         .then((users) => {
            for(let user of users){
               // console.log(user)
               const orginalDiv = document.querySelector("#user");
               orginalDiv.style.display ='none';
               const newDiv = document.createElement('div')
               newDiv.innerHTML= orginalDiv.innerHTML;
               newDiv.className="user";
               const nameH = document.querySelector('#name')
               nameH.innerHTML = user.name;
               const emailH = document.querySelector('#email')
               emailH.innerHTML = user.email;
               const parentDiv = document.getElementById("parUser")
               parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
               console.log(newDiv);
               newDiv.addEventListener("click", ()=>userEvent(user.id)) 
               console.log(user.id)
               const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
            }
            
                     return
         })
        // orderElement(user)
      }
      function getPost(userID){
         fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId='+ userID)
         .then((response) =>{
            if (response.ok) {
               return response.json() 
            }
         
         })
         .then((posts) => {
            for(let post of posts){
               const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
               const orginalPost = document.querySelector("#demo")
               console.log(orginalPost);
               // orginalPost.style.display="none";
            //     //orginalPost.innerHTML='';  
                let newPost = document.createElement('div')
                newPost.innerHTML = orginalPost.innerHTML;
                newPost.classList.remove("orginal")
                newPost.className = 'info';
            // //    //console.log('new post ',newPost);
                let postHead = document.querySelector(".postHead")
                let postP = document.querySelector(".postP")
                     postHead.innerHTML = post.title;
                     postP.innerHTML = post.body;
            // //    //const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
                     parentPosts.appendChild(newPost)
                    remove(parentPosts)
            }
                         return
         });
      }
      
      function remove(element) {
         let elementLength = element.children.length;
         console.log("element.children.length >> "+elementLength)
         if (element > 0) {
            element.firstChild.remove()
            //element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
            console.log("element.children.length from loop >> "+ elementLength)
}
  }
     getUsers()
      
     getPost()

      function userEvent(id) {
         getPost(id);
        
      }

      </script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `element > 0` to do exactly? To remove all children from an element `while (element.firstChild) element.firstChild.remove()` might be more simple.

Comment: Can you clarify more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This function supposed to work for the remove old posts

The function `remove` contains this block:

```
if(element > 0){
    element.firstChild.remove()
    console.log("element.children.length from loop >> "+ elementLength)
}
```

Given that `element` is likely a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), it is never going to be `true`, even if it is `null`.

```js
console.log(null > 0)
console.log(document.createElement('div') > 0)
```

You should use the length variable `elementLength`, which you prepared before and contains an integer:

```
if(elementLength > 0){
    element.firstChild.remove()
    console.log("element.children.length from loop >> "+ elementLength)
}
```

While this concludes why your elements never were removed, I suggest to remove the content of `parentPosts` before adding `newPost`.

```
/***
* Removes all children from element
*/
function remove(element){
  if(element){
    while(element.firstChild) element.firstChild.remove()
  }

  /*
  let elementLength = element.children.length;
  console.log("element.children.length >> "+elementLength)
  if (element > 0) {
    element.firstChild.remove()
    console.log("element.children.length from loop >> "+ elementLength)
  }
  */
}
```

Here is an adjusted snippet.

```js
function getUsers(userID){
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
   .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok){
         return response.json() 
      }
   })
   .then((users) => {
      for(let user of users){
         // console.log(user)
         const orginalDiv = document.querySelector("#user");
         orginalDiv.style.display ='none';
         
         const newDiv = document.createElement('div')
         newDiv.innerHTML= orginalDiv.innerHTML;
         newDiv.className="user";
         newDiv.addEventListener("click", () => userEvent(user.id)) ;
         
         const nameH = document.querySelector('#name')
         nameH.innerHTML = user.name;
         
         const emailH = document.querySelector('#email')
         emailH.innerHTML = user.email;
         
         const parentDiv = document.getElementById("parUser")
         parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
                  
         //REM: Not required
         //console.log(newDiv);
         //console.log(user.id)
         //const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos")
      }

  return
 })
};

function getPost(userID){
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId='+ userID)
  .then((response) => {
    if(response.ok){
       return response.json() 
    }
 })
 .then((posts) => {
    //REM: These wont change inside the loop
    const orginalPost = document.querySelector("#demo");
    const parentPosts = document.querySelector(".infos");
 
    //REM: Clear the current content
    remove(parentPosts);

    //REM: Add new content
    for(let post of posts){
      //console.log(orginalPost);

      const newPost = document.createElement('div');
      newPost.innerHTML = orginalPost.innerHTML;
      
      //REM: Setting className below, removed all other classes anyway
      //newPost.classList.remove("orginal")
      newPost.className = 'info';

      const postHead = newPost.querySelector(".postHead");
      postHead.innerHTML = post.title;
      
      const postP = newPost.querySelector(".postP");
      postP.innerHTML = post.body;
      
      parentPosts.appendChild(newPost)
    };
    
    return
  })
};

function remove(element){
  if(element){
    while(element.firstChild) element.firstChild.remove()
  }
};

function userEvent(id){
  getPost(id);
};

getUsers()
getPost()
```

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(120DEG,#c0a397,#ebe6b4);
}
.conterner{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.users{
  margin: 2px;
  background: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}
.infos{
  margin: 2px;
  background: white;
  width: 70%;
}
.user{
  border-radius: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(187, 200, 200, 0.315);
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.user:hover,
:active{
  border: rgb(224, 152, 132) 2px solid;
}
h3{
  padding: 1px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.info{
  border-radius: 23px;
  background-color: rgba(187, 200, 200, 0.331);
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 2px ;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.line{
  width: 97%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /* position: relative; */
  }
  .dispaly{
     display: none;
  }
  .orginal{
     display: none;
  }
```

```html
<main>
   <div class="conterner">
      <div class="users " >
         <div style="margin: 0 a;" id="parUser">
            <div class="user" id="user" >
               <h3 id="name"> Ahmed </h3>
               <h3 id="email"> Ahmed.ali@gmail.com </h3>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="info orginal" id="demo">
         <h5 class="postHead" > post post postpost</h5>
         <div class="line"></div>
         <p class="postP"> post post postpost</p>
      </div>

      <div class="infos">
         <div class="info">
            <h5 class="postHead" > post post postpost</h5>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <p class="postP"> post post postpost</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>
```

Comment: `  function remove(element) {
         let elementLength = element.children.length;
            element.firstChild.remove()
  } `  this It works well but when you add it in  **getPost(userID)**  just show the first three items!!

Comment: I add this `if (parentPosts.lastChild){remove(parentPosts)}` condition inside the function **getPost(userID)**  but I think it's not working?????????

Comment: In your loop, you append a post and remove a post. That logic only works if every user has the same amount of posts. If not you start removing *new posts* as *old posts*. That is why you should just remove all posts before starting your loop. You can see it in my snippet at the bottom of the post.